# Dockerized Django Project on Heroku -- User Account App Gives HTTP 500 Error

Tags: django, docker, heroku, http-status-code-500

I have just deployed a Dockerized Django project to a Heroku Hobby Dyno, and there seems to be some issues with users logging in and accessing the account portion of the website. The homepage app works perfectly, but that's about all that works.

Even as a superuser, I can access the main screen of the admin page, but when I click on one of the model names, a 500 error code is thrown. The only model I can access is the default user model Django provides. This is also the case for any users trying to access accounts. I can get new users registered and added to the User model, but they are unable to reach any portion of the website that requires being logged in--not even their profile page.

Here is my project directory:

```
project-root
>account          #this is the app causing the issues
>env              #env directory
>homescreen       #this app works fine
>media            #user-upload directory
>mementos
-.dockerignore
-.gitignore
-db.sqlite3
-Dockerfile
-manage.py
-Pipfile
-requirements.txt
```

The Heroku logs are pretty vague. Here's what I get when a user tries to access their account:

```
2020-07-30T04:04:14.923403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/account/" host=**********.herokuapp.com request_id=c9cbe319-7ff0-4dc8-8105-0b16e10d74ae fwd="35.25.10.57" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=68ms status=500 bytes=413 protocol=http
```

Same thing happens when I try accessing a model on the admin page:

```
2020-07-30T04:04:22.438655+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/account/data/" host=**********.herokuapp.com request_id=12503e78-14ce-4e84-aab7-cce40e1001c2 fwd="35.25.10.57" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=62ms status=500 bytes=413 protocol=http
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: This feels like a database issue. Check that your app is able to connect to the database or not on Heroku.

Comment: I checked to make sure the database is connected, and everything looks good with that from what I can tell. Registration does create new User-model objects, which I can see on the admin page. I can create a superuser and manage database migrations. So it seems to be connected and configured, but it’s just my own custom models that I am unable to access, and users can’t access accounts. Any other thoughts what might be going on? Perhaps it is a database issue, I just don’t know where things could be going wrong.